# Hadoop: Failed to start backup node, bad state: DROP_UNTIL_NEXT_ROLL

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have created a small Hadoop cluster setup with 1 NameNode and 1 DataNode to get hands-on.

below is my configuration files:

**Core-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://n1:9000</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
   <value>/home/admin/hdfs_store/data/secondarynamenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/admin/hdfs_store/data/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/admin/hdfs_store/data/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>n1</value>
</property>
```

I am trying to start a BackupNode where I have DataNode with below command

> hdfs namenode -backup

below is the trace is am getting

```
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSImage: Start loading edits file /home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode/current/edits_0000000000000063693-0000000000000063694
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSImage: Edits file /home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode/current/edits_0000000000000063693-0000000000000063694 of size 42 edits # 2 loaded in 0 seconds
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.NameCache: initialized with 79 entries 1482 lookups
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.LeaseManager: Number of blocks under construction: 0
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file /home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000063694 using no compression
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Image file /home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000063694 of size 5536 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 2 images with txid >= 63692
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Purging old image FSImageFile(file=/home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode/current/fsimage_0000000000000063689, cpktTxId=0000000000000063689)
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.TransferFsImage: Sending fileName: /home/admin/hdfs_store/data/namenode/current/fsimage_0000000000000063694, fileSize: 5536. Sent total: 5536 bytes. Size of last segment intended to send: -1 bytes.
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.TransferFsImage: Uploaded image with txid 63694 to namenode at http://n1:50070 in 0.021 seconds
19/03/06 05:04:36 ERROR namenode.Checkpointer: Throwable Exception in doCheckpoint: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: bad state: DROP_UNTIL_NEXT_ROLL
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.BackupImage.convergeJournalSpool(BackupImage.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Checkpointer.doCheckpoint(Checkpointer.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Checkpointer.run(Checkpointer.java:152)
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for active state
19/03/06 05:04:36 WARN namenode.LeaseManager: Encountered exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseManager.stopMonitor(LeaseManager.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.stopActiveServices(FSNamesystem.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.BackupNode$BNHAContext.stopActiveServices(BackupNode.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.BackupState.exitState(BackupState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.stop(NameNode.java:1016)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.BackupNode.stop(BackupNode.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Checkpointer.shutdown(Checkpointer.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.Checkpointer.run(Checkpointer.java:159)
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: LazyPersistFileScrubber was interrupted, exiting
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: NameNodeEditLogRoller was interrupted, exiting
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Shutting down CacheReplicationMonitor
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 50100
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 50100
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: Stopping ReplicationMonitor.
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for active state
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for standby state
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50105
19/03/06 05:04:36 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at d1/10.46.60.8
************************************************************/
```

Not able to figureout what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem in the past.
I had to specify backup node address both in namenode and backup node.

dfs.namenode.backup.addressbackupnode:50100

Br,
Tomasz Ziss

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).